# Is there any way to use "Search Result" component in a custom page

Tags: community, napili

Using the Napili community template. I want to create a special topic details page, and I would like to be able to drop the "Search Results" component that is used on the built-in topic details page onto my custom page, but it does not appear in the list of components.  Does anyone know how I can add this to my custom page.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The community cloud product does not support this yet .You might want to open an idea . Meanwhile you can build your own custom component to search whatever object you want the data to display from .